# How to fix cannot resolve symbol 'WriterException'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code

I am new in android development and, I am following  a QR code generator application tutorial using java, the developer in that tutorial throws a WriterException , while I am trying to do the same  I face this error (cannot resolve symbol 'WriterException'  ). I'm using this library
https://github.com/androidmads/QRGenerator

```
    genebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String data = qrvalue.getText().toString();
            QRGEncoder qrgEncoder= new QRGEncoder(data,null, QRGContents.Type.TEXT,500);
            try {
                // Getting QR-Code as Bitmap
               Bitmap bitmap = qrgEncoder.getBitmap();
                // Setting Bitmap to ImageView
                qrimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (WriterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: add more details - your library/sample code.. full error log

Comment: Make sure you have added ```implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'``` dependency

Answer (score 0):

Set your mouse cursor on this error and click alt+enter to import class.This error existed because maybe import havn't been declared